# Quitar botón dropdown de un DBLookupComboBox

Tags: delphi

como puedo hacer para ocultar o quitar el boton de dropdown de un componente
DBLookupComboBox?? , algo asi como la propiedad csSimple de un combobox normal.
inclusive si depende de ello hacer un componente personalizado que derive de DBLookupComboBox.
Gracias!!

Comment: Es posible que si necesitas hacer, sea indicativo de que no estás utilizando el componente correcto. Hay muchos componentes de Base de Datos; Si a un combobox qiuieres eliminarle la característica distintiva de un "combo" es que tal vez no es el componente correcto.
Otra opción (tal vez más sencilla que eliminar el botón) es utilizar un TCombobox (con la propiedad csSimpe, como comentas) y emular las caracteristicas de Base de Datos (por ejemplo, con un componente oculto  "emparejado" con este).

Comment: ¿Por qué querrías quitarle el "combo" a un "ComboBox"?. Si nos cuentas cuál es el problema que quieras resolver, quizás aparezca una mejor solución.